# npm joystick problems with node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, joystick

I am trying to use a joystick with node js, and I ran into an issue.

I installed the function with

```
npm install joystick
```

that worked well, but when I ran this code to test it:

```
// Set a deadzone of +/-3500 (out of +/-32k) and a sensitivty of 350 
var joystick = new (require('joystick'))(0, 3500, 350);
joystick.on('button', console.log);
joystick.on('axis', console.log);
```

It gave me this error:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to write this as an answer, but it is. The package you reference, [Joystick](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joystick), has as its description: "Node.js module for reading joystick data **under Linux**"

From your screenshot  you are on Windows. The error you are getting is presumably it referencing IO which is giving you what is in effect a file no found message.

Comment: Wow. I didn't even notice that. :D  That was dumb of me.

Comment: Sometimes we all need a an extra set of eyes. :-)